# Elastic Search update fields in the document

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

In ES , need to update existing fields in document. I can easily add new fields in the document .

```
POST {"doc":{"newFields":"value"}}
```

- it will add new fields into existing document. But i couldn't add this scenario.

```
{"name":"aa","otherinfo": {"hobbies":["cricket","football"]} }
```

1. Here i need to add another fields eduction fields - how can i do?
2. suppose i need to add basket ball into existing hobbies
3. remove all the fields from hobbies and add ONLY throwball

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [Update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/docs-update.html).

You can just [update with a partial document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/docs-update.html#_updates_with_a_partial_document). Example:

```
POST test/_doc/1/_update
{
  "doc" : {
    "name" : "new_name"
  }
}
```

But moreover you can update document with [scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/modules-scripting.html). Examples:

> We can add a tag to the list of tags (note, if the tag exists, it will still add it, since its a list):

```
POST test/_doc/1/_update
{
  "script" : {
    "source": "ctx._source.tags.add(params.tag)",
    "lang": "painless",
    "params" : {
      "tag" : "blue"
    }
  }
}
```

or

> We can also add a new field to the document:

```
POST test/_doc/1/_update
{
  "script" : "ctx._source.new_field = 'value_of_new_field'"
}
```

or

> Or remove a field from the document:

```
POST test/_doc/1/_update
{
  "script" : "ctx._source.remove('new_field')"
}
```

and much more.